# How is Elastigirl able to (attempt to) transmit to Nomanisan Air Traffic Control?

Tags: the-incredibles

In the original Incredibles (2004) Elastigirl attempts contact with an air traffic control tower as she's trying to land on Nomanisan Island, initially to request directions to the island's airport:

This island is essentially a private island whose airport is presumably reserved for Syndrome's business and personal use. How is Elastigirl able to transmit to a frequency that Syndrome and his team are able to pick up?

Comment: I *think* you are asking how she knew the ATC frequency, right? Such information is published for pilots even for non-public airfields. Then again, it's a movie!

Comment: She also mentions transmitting on the GUARD frequency. It would generally be pretty dumb to close all lines of communication with the outside world, even if you are a reclusive supervillain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_emergency_frequency

Comment: Guard is only used in an emergency, such as when she is targeted by the missiles, so she wasn't using it until then.

Comment: @Paulie_D Correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In her brief radio transmission Helen shifts over to the emergency ['*GUARD*' frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_emergency_frequency). She also says that she's transmitting '[*in the blind*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51565/20774)', basically telling them that she can't hear them but that she expects (or at least hopes) that they can hear her.

> [ROARING THROUGH THE CLOUDS as the jet BANKS suddenly, barely avoiding a missile that smokes past its metallic belly.]
>
> [RESUME SYNDROME'S BASE - PRISON CELL - SAME MOMENT]
>
> **HELEN'S VOICE:** *India Golf Niner niner **transmitting in the blind guard**...*
>
> **BOB:** *No!*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Incredibles - Script](https://thescriptlab.com/wp-content/uploads/scripts/the-incredibles.pdf)</sup></sub>

Helen is an accomplished pilot, perfectly capable of flying a range of different aircraft. It's not at all surprising that she would know how to use the emergency frequencies, and it's not especially surprising that Syndrome's minions were listening on a wide range of radio frequencies, even if they have no intention of responding.

Comment: I believe the US Navy monitors certain frequencies to monitor possible enemy fighters, so it’s not inconceivable that Syndrome would, too.

Comment: @moonman239 - Guard is a very common frequency to monitor. They have a tower on the island too, and an airstrip.